# cordova app works on the ripple emulator but it does not work on the device.only the title shows

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I have an angularjs app using cordova. When I run it on ripple emulator it works but when I send it to my device samsung s3 mini, the backgroung color shows and the title also shows but the content of the body does not show.

I need help. I will be grateful if someone helps me. Thanks in advance.

```
angular.module("sportsStoreAdmin", ["ngRoute",    
"ngResource","ngFileUpload"])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/login", {
templateUrl: "views/adminlogin.html",
controller: "AuthController"
});
$routeProvider.when("/main", {
templateUrl: "views/adminMain.html",
controller: "MainController"
});                                     
$routeProvider.when("/fileupload", {
templateUrl: "views/fileUpload.html",
controller: "MyController"
});         
$routeProvider.when("/loadMap", {
templateUrl: "views/loadMap.html",
controller: "MyController"
});         
$routeProvider.otherwise({
redirectTo: "/login"
});
});
```

Comment: Are you debugging at all? Maybe a deviceready event isn't firing or something. Can you post some code to see what your start page does?

Comment: I am using the index file to route to partial views. Here is the listing for the index file:

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow so I am finding it difficult to post the code. The system says that my codes are too long.

Comment: Edit the original post to add the code

Comment: I pressed the F12 key and when I run the applocation the console displayed "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onCordovaReady"

Answer (score 0):

Any errors on the console? I don't know how are you sending your app to the device but just in case you can plug it to an USB port on you computer, run `cordova run android --device` and the use Chrome to debug your app. That way you should be able to see if there is any error in the console.

Comment: I have used a usb cable to connect the device to my laptop. After running